# Failed to import new project

Tags: android

> Build  sync failed: failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.2.

I am facing this problem when i try to import my project to studio. How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you install this ? .Open `SDK Manager` and make sure you install this version yet

Comment: You need to install the build tools from SDK manager

Comment: 24.4.1         Installed
  23.1.0 rc1 Update Available: 23.1.0

Comment: I have installed this.

Comment: The package filter removed all packages. There is nothing to install.
         Please consider trying to update again without a package filter.

Comment: This is showing on my screen .Please let me know why this message is appeared on my screen after update build tool

Answer (score 0):

open your `SDK Manager`

[image]

if Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.2 is not installed then installed
or change the build version of project in `build.gradle(app)`

[image]

Comment: I have done the same but the problem is not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your project local.properties and see if the path to sdk is correct?